# How to convert xPath to JSoup query

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, jsoup

I want to convert following Xpath to Jsoup query. Can anyone help? And Is there a tool to do this?

```
//*[contains(@class, 'drop-down-container') and contains(.//span, 'Kategori')]
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

example 1:

```
[XPath]
//*[@id="docs"]/div[1]/h4/a

[JSoup]
document.select("#docs > div > h4 > a").attr("href");
```

example 2:

```
[XPath]
//*[@id="action-bar-container"]/div/div[2]/a[2]

[JSoup]
document.select("#action-bar-container > div > div:eq(1) > a:eq(1)").attr("href");
```

Comment: I know these things but I do not know how to turn them around. Your answer is not good.